# AIX: it takes 2 execution to see the true result

Tags: shell, ksh

Why every time I execute my script, I tooks 2 execution before I see the true result,

```
script_dir=/opt/scripts/x186299

smo_log=/oracle/bxcons21/base/admin/bxcons21/scripts/logs

error_txt=$script_dir/logs/SMO_error.txt

count_error=$script_dir/logs/count_error.txt

yest=$script_dir/logs/yesterday.txt

ECount=`cat $count_error`

rm $error_txt $count_error $yest

echo `TZ=MDT+48 date +%Y%m%d` > $yest

cd $smo_log

#grep -i "Error invoking command" $yest_* >> $error_txt

echo "Error invoking command" >> $error_txt

cat $error_txt | wc -l >> $count_error

if [ $ECount = 0 ];

then

    echo "SMO Backup is failed"

    exit

else

    echo "SMO Backup is succesful"

    exit

fi


if I ran this, it will show succesfull, then if I changed this part to

old

"#grep -i "Error invoking command" $yest_* >> $error_txt

"echo "Error invoking command" >> $error_txt

new

"grep -i "Error invoking command" $yest_* >> $error_txt

"#echo "Error invoking command" >> $error_txt
```

I expect to see failed message right, but unfortunately it showing succesfull then if I execute again the script, without changing, it will show the failed message.

getting bold if only used #,so I put " on grep & echo line

Comment: You don't have a variable called `yest_`, so `$yest_*` would expand to `*` and then the `*` would expand to all filenames in the current directory.  I'm not quite sure I know what you meant to do here, possibly `"${yest}_"*`.  In general, your script lacks quoting for _every_ variable expansion.  Please see https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `ECount` too early, at that moment the `count_error` file is still empty when the script executes the first time:

```
ECount=`cat $count_error`
...
grep -i "Error invoking command" $yest_* >> $error_txt
...
cat $error_txt | wc -l >> $count_error
if [ $ECount = 0 ];
```

Use

```
grep -i "Error invoking command" $yest_* >> $error_txt
...
wc -l $error_txt >> $count_error
ECount=`cat $count_error`
if [ $ECount = 0 ];
```

instead, or (if you don't need the file later on)

```
ECount=`wc -l $error_txt`
if [ $ECount = 0 ];
```

Comment: awesome, it works. Thanks a lot my friend..